# Plesk Panel 11 www prefix not working

Tags: web, webserver, plesk

i'm hosting websites from my customers using Plesk Panel 11, but when i try to reach a domain using the www. prefix, i get redirected to the Parallels Domain Default Page.

Customers keep their domain, but set the nameservers to mine, so i can manage the dns. In this way, my dns is always the master server. I already tried going to dns managing and reset the automatic www. prefix.

I have been working on this problem for two days already, and i really don't know what is going wrong.

Does anyone of you know a solution?

Comment: Did you have upgrade to plesk 11 from older version? It's a windows or linux?

Comment: It is a brand-new installation, on a linux server (ubuntu 12.04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you see "**Domain** Default Page" it's OK for new created subscription because it's a predefined content of site.

When you access site like www.domain.tld and see "**Server** Default Page" it's means that there is no "ServerAlias www.domain.tld" in last apache config file of domain.tld.

Last httpd config placed in /var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/conf/last_httpd.include

I suggest you to check domain name resolving for www.domain.tld and domain.tld and make sure that your web server is serve both domain names.